# Detecting between the lowercase and uppercase php

Tags: php

I am using this script to delete picture from my server. But at the same time I want to protect the files in my server. Not accidentally delete but I noticed that if I typed the file `index.pHp` or `index.Php` is deleted from my server. Although setting it will not delete why php or this method not know between lowercase and uppercase.

What is not done right?

```
<?php
error_reporting (0);
$thefile = $_GET ['filetodel'];
$filename = "$thefile";
//$filename = "picture1.jpg";

/*protect some files*/
if ($thefile=='index.php' or $thefile=='INDEX.PHP' or $thefile=='UPLOADS.ZIP' or $thefile=='uploads.zip' or $thefile=='del.php'or $thefile=='DEL.PHP' or $thefile==NULL or $thefile=='.htaccess' or $thefile=='.HTACCESS' )
{
exit("<h2>cannot delete $thefile</h2>");
}
if ($thefile=="$thefile")
{
if (file_exists($filename))
{
unlink ("$thefile");
echo "<h2> file $thefile is delete</h2>";
} 
else 
{
echo "<h2>The<br>";
echo "$filename<br>";
echo "Does not exist</h2>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So you know in the future, your code has to go in the question, no on a 3rd party service.

Answer (score 4):

Just convert the input to lowercase and test it once, rather than worrying about every possible mix of case:

```
if (strtolower($thefile) == 'index.php') {
  // ...
}
```

For the next iteration, you could store your protected files in an array:

```
$protected_files = array('index.php', 'uploads.zip', 'del.php', '.htaccess');

if (in_array(strtolower($thefile), $protected_files) || $thefile==NULL) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: HTML is not a great exit string argument for a 63.6k user.

Comment: Err, it's a copy-paste of his code. The `exit` call isn't really relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sigh. Are you pacified?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
if ($thefile=="$thefile")
```

as if your 1st condition for file check is false than the second condition is

```
if ($thefile=="$thefile")
```

which is always true so it will unlink the file
Also add one line as below just before 1st condition

```
$thefile = strtolower($thefile);
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment, I will fix it

Comment: just modified the answer to satisfy your 1st condition as well